Which package to apply for ordered probit model (Polr or Odinal)?
I am developing an ordered probit model. I am curious about which package to apply. I am looking into the polr function from the MASS package and the clm function from the ordinal package in R. The coefficient level of output from both models can be interpretable considering my research objective.
I wonder how a researcher decides which package to use.

@PeterFlom, if there's not already an answer of this type on CV, and if this seems on-topic, perhaps you should post that as an answer? (Maybe this should be community-wiki?) https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22which+package%22+decide

Here is a start on a more general answer for picking packages, or, at least a start of one.

Check the documentation. Not only will this give details of what the packages do, but it will give you a view of how complete the packages are.

Compare results from the different packages. If the packages give the same results, it clearly doesn't matter which you use, except some may have some good options.

Consider the reputation of the authors. Some authors have a great reputation and a long history of writing good packages. Of course, a brand new author may have written a great package, but experience does matter.

Use what is common in your field. This might help with getting a paper accepted.



I don't know if this should be a Community wiki or not. The criteria seem a bit vague.
